# PowerShell: To get all pages name created using Custom page layout

Tags: powershell, page-layout, publishing-page

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script where I I'm trying to get the all pages name which are created using particular custom page layout.

In my site I have custom page layout with name **HomePage.aspx**, and I'm trying to get all pages which are created using Home Page layout.

Suggest some PowerShell Script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below PowerShell Script to get the pages created using specific page layouts. Run this script in SharePoint 2013 Management Shell.

```
$site = get-SPSite http://sp2013vm:5555/
$web = $site.RootWeb
$pweb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web)

$pPages = $pWeb.GetPublishingPages();

$pLayouts ="HomePage.aspx" #$pweb.GetAvailablePageLayouts()

foreach ($pPage in $pPages)
{
    if ($pPage.Layout.Name -eq $pLayouts)
    {
        write-host $pPage.Title
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you!!!